# Multiply items in range in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am brand new to Python, and I'm currently taking a free online course.

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to code this simple optional problem found in my course:

## [ ] using range(x) multiply the numbers 1 through 7

## 1x2x3x4x5x6x7 = 5040

I have made a variable for the range, 7, and a variable for the product used in the loop:

```
x = 7
product = 0

for item in range(x):
```

This is where I'm stuck.
I try things in the loop like:

product = item * item

which doesn't even make any sense. I'm having a total mental block right now. I realize this should be an easy thing to do, but can't for whatever reason. I've tried making other variables like "number" and "previous_number" to make things easier for me, but I just get confused.

I need to use a for loop in this solution. I'm just not understanding the logic right now. A solution and explanation would be great! Please help!

Comment: Use a variable called previous number. For each iteration of the loop, set the previous number to the previous number times item. Initialize to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
answer = 1

for i in range(1,8):
    print("Right now, answer is", answer)
    print("Right now, i      is", i)
    print("I am going to multiply answer ({}) with i ({}) and store the result in answer".format(answer, i))
    answer = answer * i
    print("Now, answer is", answer)

print("Finally, answer is", answer)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps clarify what's going on very well :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialise `product = 1` (as `1` is the multiplicative identity) and inside your loop you simply need:

```
product *= item
```

which is short hand for:

```
product = product * item
```

In python there is also a `reduce` function that handles these types of questions:

```
In []:
import operator as op
import functools as ft

x = 7
ft.reduce(op.mul, range(1,x+1))

Out:
5040
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
x = 7
product = 1

for item in range(1, x + 1):
    product = item * product

print(product)
```

Note that product starts at one and the range function starts at one as well. Otherwise item will continue to be multiplied by zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
digit = range(1,8)    
print("digit", list(digit))  
product = 1   
for item in digit:  
    product = product * item  
    print("product is",product)
```

Comment: your answer is good but if you want it could be better by adding a description of the code...

Answer (score 0):

```
multiplication = 1
for number in range(1,8):
    multiplication *= number
digits = list(range(1,8))
print("Multiply these numbers in sequence: ", digits, "=", multiplication)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from functools import reduce

some_list = range(1, 8)

print(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, some_list))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
user_number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

number = 1

for i in range(1,user_number + 1):
    number = number * i

print(number)
```